# xconnect namespace error on CertificateWebRequestHandlerModifier

Tags: xconnect

Based on the information provided in the Sitecore documentation,

https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/103/sitecore-experience-platform/create,-retrieve,-and-search-contact-and-interaction-data.html

I am encountering an error related to a missing using directive or assembly reference when attempting to create a proof of concept (POC). Specifically, the error is related to the line of code:

`var certificateModifier = new CertificateWebRequestHandlerModifier(options);`

Can you please let me know the namespace that needs to be imported?

Answer (score 2):

From the mentioned link, Can you please replace the piece of code with the followings and verify:

```
 var xdbCollectionCert = "StoreName=My;StoreLocation=LocalMachine;FindType=FindByThumbprint;FindValue=15E6693B0AECB63DE57D991EC363CA462DC52432";
 var options = CertificateHttpClientHandlerModifierOptions.Parse(xdbCollectionCert);

 var certificateModifier = new CertificateHttpClientHandlerModifier(options);
```

also instead of

```
var certificateModifier = new CertificateWebRequestHandlerModifier(options);
```

try with and verify. Hope it helps you.

```
 var certificateModifier = new CertificateHttpClientHandlerModifier(options);
```

If you will check the `Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web` namespace you will find that `CertificateWebRequestHandlerModifier` renamed with `CertificateHttpClientHandlerModifier`.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It lives in `Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web`.

```
using Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web;
```